# How I can connect local sql database from Oracle VM OBIEE

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc, obiee

I am using Oracle VM for OBIEE and I want to connect my local SQL server DB

How I can do it?  Are they any ODBC for vm machine?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to connect to and from VMs, the tricky part is figuring out how the IP addresses and overall networking are setup. There's nothing "special" concerning odbc connecting to a physical or virtual machine.

Comment: ı found one solution  for it but i could not do it http://rnm1978.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/querying-sql-server-from-obiee-running-on-unix/                                                       is it corrent solution what do u think ?

Comment: That article may have points about using a Linux OBIEE machine to connect to SQL Server, but it says nothing about VMs or network configuration. So I would say it is incomplete for your purposes.